# Iterating through a csv and printing out specific elements

Tags: text-processing, csv

I've got an interesting problem I'm not quite sure how best to tackle, with iterating through a list. With the following format -

```
element, date, unixTime, value
CZ, 12/27/2007 15:55, 1198788900, 42346
CZ, 12/27/2007 17:30, 1198794600, -10543
I, 12/27/2007 19:05, 1198800300, 4475
```

I want to iterate through, for each unique element, and each date, and get the sign of the "value" column. For instance, I would want 2 lines for 12/27/2007, one for both CZ and I. CZ would be negative because the line that happened at the last part of the day had a negative value, and I would be positive. Then do that again for 12/28, 12/29, etc, for many different elements. I could iterate through this with a nested for loop, but it's a giant file and would be much better to find a way to iterate through the file, sorted by date, only once. I'm a little stuck on how to do this most efficiently. I'm not sure whether bash is suitable for this, or some other language like perl or python.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange.  Suggest you add an example of what *output* you'd like to see, in much the same way as you've shown the *input*.

Comment: Please state or verify whether the dates and times for each element are sorted, (i.e. if there are *n* "CZ" *element*s, the intent is to always print the *nth* "CZ" *value*).

Comment: This sort of thing is crying out for a quick `awk` script, but I'm a little unclear on what you're looking for in terms of the output.  As per @steve's comment, if you could edit that into your answer, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the input data *foo*:

```
echo 'element, date, unixTime, value
CZ, 12/27/2007 15:55, 1198788900, 42346
CZ, 12/27/2007 17:30, 1198794600, -10543
I, 12/27/2007 19:05, 1198800300, 4475' > foo
```

Run *GNU* [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) on *foo*:

```
datamash -t, --header-in -g 1 last 4 < foo
```

Output:

```
CZ, -10543
I, 4475
```

---

The more formal switch names for `datamash` may make the above clearer, plus I've added header names, (if counting columns is inconvenient):

```
datamash --field-separator=',' --header-in --group=element last " value" < foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @agc has correctly interpreted the output you require, plain old `awk` can be used.

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{a[$1]=$4}END{for(x in a){print x","a[x]}}' foo
CZ, -10543
I, 4475
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your file is pre-sorted makes it tractable using `sed` where at any given point in time the `sed pattern space` holds no more than `2 lines`.

```
sed -e '
   $!{
      N
      /^\([^,]*\),[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]].*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\n\1,[[:space:]]\{1,\}\2[[:space:]]/D
   }
   s/^\([^,]*\),[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]].*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\(\n\)/\1 \3\4/
   /\n/!s/^\([^,]*\),[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]].*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)/\1 \3/
   P;D
' yourfile
```

## Brief

```
We always keep 2 lines in the pattern space and note the time when there
is a change in the 1st field. So long as we keep encountering the same
first two fields, we keep chopping off the previous line and reading in
the next. And on a transition we print the 1st and last fields of the 
previous line, print it, remove upto the newline, and go back for more
with whats left in the pattern space.
```